# Subgroup with an element raised to powers

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group written multiplicatively. Let $g \in G$. Let $H=
\{g,g^2,g^3,...\}$ denote the set of all powers of g. Show that H is a subgroup of G and show why this doesn't hold when G is infinite.

I know that we need to show $\forall \ h,h' \in H$, $h*h' \in H$ and the inverse of $h \in G$ is also in H. Thus $h^{-1} \in G$ and $\in H$.

The first part seems self-intuitive since we have a finite group and it must repeat itself at some point, but I am having issues with the inverse part. Additionally, I don't know how to provide a counterexample when G is infinite.

Comment: Have you considered the simplest of all infinite groups?

Comment: What is the simplest of infinite groups? $(\mathbb Z, +)$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: When $G$ is finite, powers of $g$ would eventually repeat. Suppose $g^m = g^n$ where $m > n$. This implies $g^{m - n}$ is the identity.